# c# Anonymous Methods variable scope strange behavior with yield return,Is a compiler bug or work as intend?

Tags: c#

I am using yield return stuff as coroutine in my unity 3d program.

I am using Unity3d 4.3 with c# 3.5.

If this is a bug in c#,where should I report it to c# team?

```
public class ClosureTest : TestMonoBehaviour { 
   public void doTest() {
        var a = Test3();
        a.MoveNext();
        a.MoveNext();

    }
    class Ctest2 {
        public int a;
    }
    class Ctest1 {
        public Ctest2 t2;
    }


    IEnumerator Test3() {
        yield return null;

        var c2FuncList = new List<Func<Ctest2>>();
        var c1List = new List<Ctest1>();
        for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            var ic1 = new Ctest1();
            ic1.t2 = new Ctest2();
            ic1.t2.a = i;
            c1List.Add(ic1);
        }
        foreach (var ic1 in c1List)
        {
            var ic2 = ic1.t2;
            c2FuncList.Add(delegate {
                return ic2;
            });
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            Equal(c2FuncList[i]().a, i); // always 2.
        }
    }
}
```

If I run doTest,Equal in that class will say need 0,but get 2.

Comment: There is a work around: put Anonymous Methods stuff into another normal function,It will work as expect..

Comment: Your code doesn't make sense ans you yield return null directly in Test3

Comment: I use yield return as coroutine ,I delete all coroutine relative stuff to make problem simple. yield return null means wait for next update in Unity 3d.BTW if I do not yield return some stuff, compiler may generate other IL code.